Java Spring Softwaretest json response is empty. Why?
I'm working on a fun project with some random person data (from java-faker) to learn more aboud java, spring, api, thymeleaf, softwaretests...
-> my-project-from-gitlab
Besides many small problems the softwaretests with junit, spring, mockmvc are running, but not working. The code with branch junit-test-and-post-request will connect to api and controller with mockmvc, but the resulting json response is empty.
I tried and copied many other solutions and ideas from other people who showed their ways with more or less similar codes, but all not working for me :( Maybe theres somewhere a wrong used annotation or wrong lib version.
File content with testcode (pls ignore the nested classes):
package com.example.demo;

import com.example.demo.controller.PersonController;
import com.example.demo.entity.Person;
import com.example.demo.service.PersonService;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayName;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Nested;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.test.context.event.annotation.AfterTestClass;
import org.springframework.test.context.event.annotation.BeforeTestClass;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultHandlers;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers;
import org.springframework.util.Assert;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import static org.springframework.test.util.AssertionErrors.assertEquals;

@WebMvcTest(PersonController.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
//@SpringBootTest
//@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class PersonTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Mock
    private PersonController personController;

    @InjectMocks
    PersonService personService;

    static final String url = "http://localhost:8000";

    //static final String urlCreateData = "http://localhost:8000/createMoreData?username=admin&pw=secret";
    static final String urlCreateData = "http://localhost:8000?username=admin&pw=secret";

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PersonTest.class);

    private List<Person> personList;

    @DisplayName("Start -> Request")
    @BeforeTestClass
    public void start() throws Exception {
        log.info("Start -> Request");
        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders
                        .get(urlCreateData)
                        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
        personList.addAll(PersonService.createNewData(10));
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Test. Get new person list.size")
    void testPersonObjectList(){
        //when(PersonService.createNewData(10)).
        assertEquals(
        "Test: Create new list with objects with size of 10",
        10,
                PersonService.createNewData(10).size());
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Test. Get new person != null")
    void testPersonObjectNotNull(){
        Assert.notNull(
                PersonService.createNewData().get(0),
                "Test: Get new person != null");
    }

    @Test
    public void testPersonListCountObjects(){
         List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>(PersonService.createNewData(10));
         assertEquals("Created new list with 10 objects", 10, personList.size());
         personList.addAll(PersonService.createNewData(10));
         assertEquals("Expanded list with 10 more objects", 20, personList.size());
    }

    @Test
    public void testStatusOk() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders
                .get(url)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                )
                .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print())
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk())
                ;
    }

    @Test
    public void testStatusOkAndJsonPathExists() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders
                .get(url)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                )
                .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print())
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk())
                .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$."+personService.NAME_FOR_MODEL_DATA).exists())
                ;
    }

    @AfterTestClass
    @DisplayName("End -> Clean")
    public void clean() {
        log.info("End -> Clean");
        personService.setCREATE_DATA_FOR_TEST(false);
    }
}



File content of controller:

package com.example.demo.controller;

import com.example.demo.entity.Person;
import com.example.demo.repository.PersonRepository;
import com.example.demo.service.PersonService;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import static com.example.demo.service.PersonService.*;

@RestController
//@Controller
//@RequestMapping("/index.html")
//@RequestMapping("/")
@RequestMapping("")
@EnableWebMvc
public class PersonController {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PersonController.class);

    @Autowired
    Environment environment;

    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    PersonRepository personRepository;

    @Autowired
    PersonService personService;

    final String htmlFile = "index";

    @PostMapping("/createMoreData")
    @ResponseStatus(code = HttpStatus.OK)
    public ModelAndView createMoreData(
            @RequestParam(required = false) String username,
            @RequestParam(required = false) String pw,
            Model model,
            HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse
    ){
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName(htmlFile);
        switch (isAdminAccount(username, pw)) {
            case YES -> {
                if(isDatabaseEmpty()) {
                    createNewData(true);
                    model.addAttribute("message",
                        "Created new data with admin account(s).");
                } else {
                    createNewData();
                    model.addAttribute("message",
                        "Created new data.");
                }
                model.addAttribute(personService.NAME_FOR_MODEL_DATA, getDataWithoutSensibleInfos(true, personRepository.findAll()));
                model.addAttribute(personService.NAME_FOR_MODEL_PERMISSION, true);
            }
            case EMPTY_PARAMETER -> {
                log.error(PersonService.IsAdmin.EMPTY_PARAMETER.toString());
                model.addAttribute(personService.NAME_FOR_MODEL_MESSAGE,
                        "Did not create new data: " + PersonService.IsAdmin.EMPTY_PARAMETER.toString());
                httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
                model.addAttribute(personService.NAME_FOR_MODEL_DATA, getDataWithoutSensibleInfos(false, personRepository.findAll()));
                model.addAttribute(personService.NAME_FOR_MODEL_PERMISSION, false);
            }
            case WRONG_PARAMETER -> {
                log.error(PersonService.IsAdmin.WRONG_PARAMETER.toString());
                model.addAttribute(personService.NAME_FOR_MODEL_MESSAGE,
                        "Did not create new data: " + PersonService.IsAdmin.WRONG_PARAMETER.toString());
                httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_BAD_REQUEST);
                model.addAttribute(personService.NAME_FOR_MODEL_DATA, getDataWithoutSensibleInfos(false, personRepository.findAll()));
                model.addAttribute(personService.NAME_FOR_MODEL_PERMISSION, false);
            }
        }
        return modelAndView;
    }

    @GetMapping("")
    public ModelAndView loadData(
            @RequestParam(required = false) String username,
            @RequestParam(required = false) String pw,
            Model model
    ){
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName(htmlFile);
        switch (isAdminAccount(username, pw)) {
            case YES -> {
                log.info(IsAdmin.YES.toString());
                if(personService.CREATE_DB_DATA_ON_STARTUP && isDatabaseEmpty()) {
                    createNewData(true);
                    model.addAttribute(personService.NAME_FOR_MODEL_MESSAGE, "Created new data with admin account(s).");
                }
                model.addAttribute(personService.NAME_FOR_MODEL_DATA, getDataWithoutSensibleInfos(true, personRepository.findAll()));
            }
            case EMPTY_PARAMETER -> {
                log.error(IsAdmin.EMPTY_PARAMETER.toString());
                model.addAttribute(personService.NAME_FOR_MODEL_PERMISSION, false);
                model.addAttribute(personService.NAME_FOR_MODEL_MESSAGE, IsAdmin.EMPTY_PARAMETER.toString());
                model.addAttribute(personService.NAME_FOR_MODEL_DATA, getDataWithoutSensibleInfos(false, personRepository.findByIsAdminFalse()));
            }
            case WRONG_PARAMETER -> {
                log.error(IsAdmin.WRONG_PARAMETER.toString());
                model.addAttribute(personService.NAME_FOR_MODEL_PERMISSION, false);
                model.addAttribute(personService.NAME_FOR_MODEL_MESSAGE, IsAdmin.WRONG_PARAMETER.toString());
                model.addAttribute(personService.NAME_FOR_MODEL_DATA, getDataWithoutSensibleInfos(false, personRepository.findByIsAdminFalse()));
            }
        }
        return modelAndView;
    }
    private void createNewDataIfNotCreated(){
        if(isDatabaseEmpty()){
            List<Person> personList = createNewDataWithAdmin();
            log.info("Saving all "+personList.size()+" data to database.");
            personRepository.saveAll(personList);
        }
    }
    private void createNewData(){
        createNewData(false);
    }
    private void createNewData(boolean withAdmin){
        List<Person> personList = null;
        if(withAdmin) {
            personList = createNewDataWithAdmin();
        } else {
            personList = PersonService.createNewData();
        }
        log.info("Saving all " + personList.size() + " data to database.");
        personRepository.saveAll(personList);
    }
    private boolean isDatabaseEmpty(){
        return jdbcTemplate.queryForList("select * from " + personService.DATABASE_NAME + " limit 1;").isEmpty();
    }
}


Error messages like: Somewhere wrong injected lib, missing templates, jdbctemplate in wrong class and more.
Current message only for starting tests (Rest of program works):
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field jdbcTemplate in com.example.demo.controller.PersonController required a bean of type 'org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate' that could not be found.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Sorry, but this site is not a discussion forum or programming tutorial site.
Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and read [Ask] to learn how to use this site effectively.
Also read
Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?

Thx for comment @JimGarrison. I don't aks for discussion or tutorial (btw this is one solution of tutorials that I visited). I ask for someone to help me to get my code working because I'm out of ideas with best-practice-solutions. I'm pretty sure that this is one topic to ask on this site. Misunderstanding?

I cloned your gitlab-repository and I found a problem that might fix your issue.
In the controller, you need to mention that it is a @RestController.
So instead of
//@RestController

Use
@RestController

(link to the line)

Thx ... and sry. The repo does not know my current code, I forgot one commit. (I should not write text at that time again) :( Restcontroller is used, unfortunately testing does not work :(. Question edited with current code.

I cannot paste the error log -> too many lines of text :(

@kasper2083 You could use https://pastebin.com/ for the huge logfiles.

-> https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CJVxoLvNyKVIgOPANrceQJ1iE67umQIG/view?usp=drive_link. (Didn't find on option for public sharing on pastebin.com :( )
